# Linear function gradient descent

Tags: python, optimization, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement a gradient descent algorithm for a simple linear function:

```
y(x) = x
```

Where initial hypothesis function is:

```
h(x) = 0.5 * x
```

and learning rate:

```
alpha = 0.1
```

[image]

Target function graph is blue and hypothesis is green.

Cost function:

```
J = 1/2m * sum[(h(x) - y(x)) * (h(x) - y(x))]
```

Gradient descent:

```
q = q - alpha/m * sum[(h(x) - y(x)) * x]
```

My implementation does not converge:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def y(x):
    return x

def get_h(q):
    """ Create hypothesis function
    
        Args:
            q - coefficient to multiply x with
            
        Returns:
            h(x) - hypothesis function
    """
    return lambda x: q*x 

def j(x, y, h):
    """Calculte a single value of a cost function 
    
        Args:
            x - target function argument values
            y - target function
            h - hypothesis function
            
        Returns:
            Value of a cost function for the given hypothesis function
    """
    m = len(x)
    return (1/(2*m)) * np.sum( np.power( (y(x) -h(x)),2 ) )

def df(h, y, xs):
    """Calculate gradient of a cost function
    
        Args:
            h - hypothesis function
            y - target function
            xs - x values
            
        Returns:
            differential of a cost function for a hypothesis with given q
            
    """
    df = np.sum((h(xs)-y(xs))*xs) / len(xs)
    return df

xs = np.array(range(100))
ys = y(xs)
hs = h(xs)

costs = []
qs = []
q = 0.5
alpha = 0.1
h = get_h(0.5) # initial hypothesis function
iters = 10
for i in range(iters):
    cost = j(xs,y,h)
    costs.append(cost)
    qs.append(q)
    print("q: {} --- cost: {}".format(q,cost))
    df_cost = df(h, y, xs)
    q = q - alpha * df_cost  # update coefficient
    h = get_h(q) # new hypothesis
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I account for q0 even if my target function intercept is zero?

**Update / Solution**

Answer from `gunes` is correct, the problem was with too big learning rate `alpha = 0.1`. Hypothesis function converges with target function even with `alpha = 0.0001` and 30 iterations as opposed to  `alpha = 1E-5` and 100 iterations as `gunes` has suggested.

This updated code shows how it all works:

```
costs = []
df_costs = [] # cost differential values
qs = [] # cost parameters
q = 0.5 # initial coast parameter
h = get_h(0.5) # initial hypothesis function
alpha = 0.0001 # learning rate
iters = 30 # number of gradient descent itterations

_=plt.plot(xs,ys) # plot target function
for i in range(iters):
    _=plt.plot(xs,h(xs)) # plot hypothesis 
    cost = j(xs,y,h) # current cost
    costs.append(cost)
    qs.append(q) # current cost function parameter
    #print("q: {} --- cost: {}".format(q,cost))
    df_cost = df(h, y, xs) # get differential of the cost
    df_costs.append(df_cost)
    #print("df_cost: ",df_cost)
    q = q - alpha * df_cost  # update hypothesis parameter 
    h = get_h(q) # get new hypothesis
    
_=plt.title("Hypothesis converges with target")
_=plt.show()
_=plt.close()
```

[image]

```
_=plt.title("Costs")
_=plt.xlabel("Iterations")
_=plt.plot(range(iters), costs)
_=plt.show()
_=plt.close()
```

[image]

```
_=plt.title("Cost differentials")
_=plt.xlabel("Iterations")
_=plt.plot(range(iters), df_costs)
_=plt.show()
_=plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: You can answer your own question by typing your solution in the Answer box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gradients and update rules are correct. It's just you're using a large learning rate for your data, because your gradients are large. Try $\alpha=10^{-5}$ and $100$ iterations. You'll see that it'll converge.

Comment: Please see update of my question

Comment: Yeah, my $\alpha$ was just a suggestion for a small value.

Comment: Thanks for your help!